# Why my React component does not rerender when Set state was changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can't get where is the problem hiding. I'm changing state but the component not rerender. So this is my code:

```js
export const InterestsPupup: React.FC = ({interests, title, buttonText}) => {
  const [activeItems, setActiveItems] = useState(new Set())

  const clickOnItemHandler = (item: string) => {
    let newSet = activeItems
    activeItems.has(item) ? newSet.delete(item) : newSet.add(item)
    setActiveItems(prev => newSet)
  }

  return (
        <div className={styles.Container__main}>
            {interests.map((item , index) => {
              return (
                <div
                  key={index}
                  className={activeItems.has(item) ? clsx(styles.item, styles.item_active) : styles.item}
                  onClick={() => clickOnItemHandler(item)}
                >{item}</div>
              )
            })}
        </div>
  );
};
```

There is my state in shape of `Set`, i'm changing that state and nothing is happens, only after i reopen that popup component. So my state changes but the component doesn't rerender

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're changing your state in place, you need to ensure you are passing in a new set object and not the same set object reference. Although you've modified the set, you're still passing through the same set object:

```js
setActiveItems(currSet => {
  const newSet = new Set(currSet);
  if(newSet.has(item))
    newSet.delete(item);
  else
    newSet.add(item);
  return newSet;
});
```

I've replaced the ternary with an if-statement. The conditional operator `? :` is generally used when you want to use the value that it returns, however, in your case the value isn't being used, so an if-statement is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You should write like this:

```
setActiveItems(newSet);
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone just wrote a comment that helped and deleted it right after, but thank you
The answer was:
I just had to change this

```js
let newSet = activeItems
```

On this:

```js
let newSet = new Set([...activeItems])
```